# Reset password by using Auth passport not revoke the access token automatically | Laravel

Tags: laravel, access-token, laravel-passport

I have an application of LARAVEL in which I implemented passport (Password Grant Type) with default auth system. When a user request for reset password I will send password token to user's email and password reset process works fine.

But My question is after successfully reset user password then all the access tokens that are associated with that user should be automatically revoked or deleted! I was thinking that this process is automatically or I missed something...

```
$response = $this->broker()->reset(
    $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    }
);
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
    if ($response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
        return $this->respond(["status"=>"success","success"=>1 , 'message' => trans('passwords.reset')]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([ 'status' => "fail", 'success' => 0,'error' => 202, 'message' => trans($response) ], 202);
    }
}
```

Or should I need to do this process manually like this?

```
$response = $this->broker()->reset(
    $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    }
);
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
    if ($response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
    /* The following code is added */
        $userTokens = User::whereEmail($data['email'])->first()->tokens;
            foreach($userTokens as $token) {
                $token->delete();   
            }
        return $this->respond(["status"=>"success","success"=>1 , 'message' => trans('passwords.reset')]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([ 'status' => "fail", 'success' => 0,'error' => 202, 'message' => trans($response) ], 202);
    }
}
```